# SQL PIVOT Date as day not coming in proper order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get records from previous month's last day  to current month's last day with below code

```
    SELECT [DAY],
       [N-1 HSD],
       [N-2 HSD],
       [N-6 HSD],
       DIP,
       [STOCK LTR],
       [PURRCHASE LTR],
       [STOCK LTR] + [PURRCHASE LTR] AS [Total Ltr],
       Isnull([TESTING], 0) AS Testing,
       0 AS [Sales As Reading],
       0 AS [Sales As Dip],
       0 AS [Diff Ltr],

  (SELECT TOP (1) _RATE
   FROM _PRODUCTRATE
   WHERE _ISDELETED = N'1'
     AND _PRODUCTID_PK = N'154eeb16-0c5c-44e4-b5cc-b0f30a22098f'
     AND _DATE <= _RATEDATE
   ORDER BY _DATE DESC) AS [Rate Rs],
       0 AS [Amount Rs]
FROM
  (SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT Day(DBO._DSRENTRY._DSRENTRYDATE) AS [Day],
                            DBO._DSRENTRYDET._CLOSING,
                            DBO._DSRENTRY._DIPSCALE AS DIP,
                            DBO._DSRENTRY._DIP AS [Stock Ltr],
                            DBO._DSRENTRY._TESTINGQTY AS [Testing],
                            DBO._NOZZLE._NOZZLENAME,

     (SELECT Isnull(Sum(_QTY), 0) AS Expr1
      FROM DBO._TANKVACCANT
      WHERE (_ISDELETED = N'1')
        AND (_TANKID_PK = N'88e31d8c-acf5-4c09-a91f-28577c66d070')
        AND (_TANKVACCANTDATE = _DSRENTRYDATE)
        AND (_COMPANYID_PK = N'747c28ad-2924-4456-91fe-6f4f7b0db3fd')
        AND (_WORKGROUPNAME = N'SRV')) AS [Purrchase Ltr],
                            DBO._DSRENTRY._DSRENTRYDATE AS _RATEDATE
   FROM DBO._NOZZLE
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN DBO._DSRENTRYDET ON DBO._NOZZLE._NOZZLEID_PK = DBO._DSRENTRYDET._NOZZLEID_PK
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN DBO._DSRENTRY ON DBO._DSRENTRYDET._DSRENTRYID_PK = DBO._DSRENTRY._DSRENTRYID_PK
   WHERE (DBO._DSRENTRYDET._ISDELETED = N'1')
     AND (DBO._DSRENTRY._COMPANYID_PK = N'747c28ad-2924-4456-91fe-6f4f7b0db3fd')
     AND (DBO._DSRENTRYDET._COMPANYID_PK = N'747c28ad-2924-4456-91fe-6f4f7b0db3fd')
     AND (DBO._NOZZLE._COMPANYID_PK = N'747c28ad-2924-4456-91fe-6f4f7b0db3fd')
     AND (DBO._DSRENTRY._WORKGROUPNAME = N'SRV')
     AND (DBO._DSRENTRYDET._WORKGROUPNAME = N'SRV')
     AND (DBO._NOZZLE._WORKGROUPNAME = N'SRV')
     AND (DBO._DSRENTRY._ISDELETED = N'1')
     AND (DBO._NOZZLE._ISDELETED = N'1')
     AND (DBO._DSRENTRY._DSRENTRYDATE >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '31.08.2017 00:00:00', 105))
     AND (DBO._DSRENTRY._DSRENTRYDATE <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '30.09.2017 23:59:59', 105))
     AND (DBO._DSRENTRY._TANKID_PK = N'88e31d8c-acf5-4c09-a91f-28577c66d070')
   ORDER BY DBO._DSRENTRY._DSRENTRYDATE) AS DERIVEDTBL_1 PIVOT(Sum(_CLOSING)
                                                               FOR _NOZZLENAME IN ([N-1 HSD], [N-2 HSD], [N-6 HSD])) AS PVTTABLE
```

below is the output

```
DAY N-1 HSD N-2 HSD N-6 HSD DIP STOCK LTR   PURRCHASE LTR   Total Ltr   Testing Sales As Reading    Sales As Dip    Diff Ltr    Rate Rs Amount Rs
1   1886247.00  1139460.00  391836.00   140.00  15319.00    0.00    15319.00    10.00   0   0   0   59.86   0
.........
.........
.........
29  1909720.00  1147850.00  397467.00   102.40  10473.00    0.00    10473.00    10.00   0   0   0   61.57   0
30  1910934.00  1148180.00  397467.00   90.60   8932.00 6000.00 14932.00    10.00   0   0   0   61.65   0
31  1885620.00  1139191.00  391788.00   70.00   6310.00 10000.00    16310.00    10.00   0   0   0   59.78   0
```

As showing in output the last recod which is `31    1885620.00  1139191.00  391788.00   70.00   6310.00 10000.00    16310.00    10.00   0   0   0   59.78   0` is showing into bottom but this should be first,

If I changed `Day(DBO._DSRENTRY._DSRENTRYDATE)` to `DBO._DSRENTRY._DSRENTRYDATE` then records are comming in proper order but its giving me full date and time.
like below

```
DAY N-1 HSD N-2 HSD N-6 HSD DIP STOCK LTR   PURRCHASE LTR   Total Ltr   Testing Sales As Reading    Sales As Dip    Diff Ltr    Rate Rs Amount Rs
2017-08-31 00:00:00.000 1885620.00  1139191.00  391788.00   70.00   6310.00 10000.00    16310.00    10.00   0   0   0   59.78   0
2017-09-01 00:00:00.000 1886247.00  1139460.00  391836.00   140.00  15319.00    0.00    15319.00    10.00   0   0   0   59.86   0
2017-09-02 00:00:00.000 1887258.00  1139601.00  391938.00   130.00  14062.00    0.00    14062.00    10.00   0   0   0   59.94   0
----------------------------
----------------------------
2017-09-29 00:00:00.000 1909720.00  1147850.00  397467.00   102.40  10473.00    0.00    10473.00    10.00   0   0   0   61.57   0
2017-09-30 00:00:00.000 1910934.00  1148180.00  397467.00   90.60   8932.00 6000.00 14932.00    10.00   0   0   0   61.65   0
```

But I need only day not full datetime,

How I archived this.

Comment: Just write DAY(Day) in the top of your SQL then it will convert it to days only or order by your Day descending instead of ASC as you do now.

Comment: Add a column with `dense_rank` and order by `DBO._DSRENTRY._DSRENTRYDATE`

Comment: On a different note, please don't be afraid to use whitespace to format your queries. A SQL query with everything aligned to the left is very difficult to read.

Answer (score 1):

Using `DATEPART(DAY, [Day])`helps to order your output. Please add it in the select clause and order by the same column to get the sorted output.